# Change font size of specific chapter

Tags: chapters, fontsize

I have set the options of my chapter titles which are fine. However, for one specific chapter title (statement of authorship) I would prefer the title to be smaller than all the preceeding chapter titles before. Is it possible to change the font size, and maybe even the positioning, of one specific chapter title?

```
\chapter*{Statement of authorship}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `titlesec` and do this inside a group so that changes are applied only to a chapter

```
\bgroup
\titleformat{\chapter}{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}  %% remove \filcenter if not needed
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\chapter*{Statement of authorship}
\egroup
```

If the chapter comes at the end, no need of `\egroup` and `\bgroup`. Also `\filcenter` puts the chapter at the center. Change `\large` to whatever you like.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\bgroup
\titleformat{\chapter}{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}  %% remove \filcenter if not needed
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\chapter*{Statement of authorship}
\egroup
\chapter{Some chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I adapt this to a document in which I have a master file and I then insert chapters using the ´\include´ command. I Have been trying most variations to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need something easy as a font size change, you can just add this to your `\chapter*{}`-command. Not beautiful, but easy:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\pdfpageheight 9cm 

\begin{document}
\chapter*{normal}
\chapter*{\hspace{3cm}\small changed}
\chapter*{normal again}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Note: When you use an unstarred caption instead, do not forget to do `\chapter[changed]{\hspace{3cm}\small changed}` in order to get the heading right in your table of content